# Back up proprietary GPU driver?

Tags: 16.04, backup, proprietary

I'm about to upgrade my motherboard in my computer. From my understanding it is possible that I can get problems with the motherboard drivers if I don't reinstall Ubuntu. Right now I cannot get my computer connected to the internet. I have a proprietary graphics driver installed and I need it for what I do. So here's my question. Is there any way I can back up the graphics driver on another hard drive and reinstall the driver if I need to do a clean install of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding it is possible that I can get problems with the **motherboard drivers** if I don't reinstall Ubuntu.

Says who? Those drivers are generic.

> Is there any way I can back up the graphics driver on another hard drive and reinstall the driver if I need to do a clean install of Ubuntu?

Why did you ask about the graphics driver? You mentioned motherboard before. The DEB installer file will be in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`; if you want you can copy it from there. Otherwise you will need to download it from the web.

But you should not have to. From my experience removing proprietary drivers before you move your hard disk to another system should just work. Ubuntu will rebuild the device drivers every time you boot and will use the generic drivers for everything, including you graphics card, unless you have proprietary drivers installed.  I would file a bug if it does not.

- In case you start using a newer graphics card from the same manufacturer check if your current graphics card is supported by the driver. Is this is so or if you intend to keep the current graphics card you can keep your old Ubuntu and just connect the hard disk to the slot on the motherboard.
- If you start using a newer graphics card not supported by the current driver or if you start using a different graphics card and switch to AMD from nVidia or nVidia to AMD (or any the manufacturer) remove the graphics card driver from your current install and then connect the hard disk to the new motherboard.

  Booting the system will then use the generic driver, it might fall back to "low graphics mode" but you can then always install the graphics card driver after you have an internet connection. From command line if need be.